# Query inner ID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections

1)User -> With fields,

```
name as String
emailId as String
```

2)

Rating -> With fields,

```
 `userId as String.` (This will be the ID of the user and Foreign Key as per SQL)
 comment as String`
```

I have created a record for the user which looks like

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "565fe1294a27a93449751a9a"
    },
    "name": "Some name",
    "email": "somemail@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2015-12-03T06:28:57.904Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2015-12-03T06:28:57.904Z"
    }
}
```

I have create a record for the Rating which looks like

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "565fefa30878764428d96be1"
    },
    "userId": "565fe1294a27a93449751a9a",
    "comment": "just a test comment",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2015-12-03T07:30:43.409Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2015-12-03T07:30:43.409Z"
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a query where all the rating done by the user along with the user document are returned.

If I make a query like

```
db.user.find({
   "userId" :"565fe1294a27a93449751a9a"
})
```

I get the result like

```
{
    "id": "565fefa30878764428d96be1",
    "userId": "565fe1294a27a93449751a9a",
    "comment": "just a test comment"
}
```

But I want the user object as well in it something like.

```
{
    "id": "565fefa30878764428d96be1",
    "user": { "name": "Some name",
       "email": "somemail@gmail.com",
       "id": "565fe1294a27a93449751a9a"
    },
    "comment": "just a test comment"
}
```

Or even something like this will work as well

```
"rating": {
    "id": "565fefa30878764428d96be1",
    "userId": "565fe1294a27a93449751a9a",
    "comment": "just a test comment"
},
"user": {
    "id": "565fefa30878764428d96be1",
    "userId": "565fe1294a27a93449751a9a",
    "comment": "just a test comment"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to change schema. You need to change user type from string to reference. If you add reference of User in rating, then that will be easy. If you add reference of User schema then you can populate user on rating. Then will get user info with rating.

example of reference :

```
User: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
```

Comment: I user sails and waterline and as per this document i dont see a reference type. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes

Comment: You need to work with mongodb. Check this link : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thank you but i got the exact solution here. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Found my exact solution here. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many

Technically it creates two queries in the backend. Found this out by the response time.

But anyways it solves my problem.